# updated_at field in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

Does the `updated_at` field in Mangento keep a running log of all time stamps? or does it just replace the time stamp with the most current time stamp each update and/or save? I'd like to see how many times each product was updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `updated_at` field is a simple `timestamp` field on the product entity table.  Thus, it can only hold one value.  I am not aware of Magento storing a running history.   However, this should be a fairly simple module to create using a custom table and an observer that executes any time a product is saved.